# Search backward through a string using a regex (in Python)?

Tags: python, regex

**Context**
I'm parsing some code and want to match the doxygen comments before a function. However, because I want to match for a specific function name, getting only the immediately previous comment is giving me problems.

**Current Approach**

```
import re  
function_re = re.compile(
    r"\/\*\*(.+)\*\/\s*void\s+(\w+)\s*::\s*function_name\s*\(\s*\)\s*")  
function_match = function_re.search(file_string)
if function_match:  
    function_doc_str = update_match.group(2)
```

**Problem with Current Approach**
The current approach matches doxygen from earlier functions, giving me a result that is the wrong doxygen comment.

**Question**
Is there a way to search backward through a string using the Python Regex library?
It seems like my problem is that the more restrictive (less frequently occurring part) is the function signature, "void function()"

**Possible better question**
Is there a better (easier) approach that I'm missing?

Comment: I am very interested in helping you but I am not familiar with Doxygen. Can you post some code? By the way, you can also look into "lookbehide" and "lookahead". I am sure that it will help you.

Comment: Umm, this is not the case when you can reverse your input and pattern strings (or make them appear reversed via a index-recalculating wrapper) and search/regex in a usual way (I've got no experience with regex, yes)?

Answer (score 2):

simplest way is to just use a group, you don't need to go backwards...

```
 (commentRegex)functionRegex
```

Then just extract group 1. You will need to run in multi-line mode to get it working, i don't know python so i can't be more helpful.

It's also possible with lookahead assertions, but this way is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use a regex that only matches doxymentation that's immediately before the function. Maybe something like this (simplified example):

```
import re

test = """

/**
    @doxygen comment
*/
void function()
{
}

"""

doxygenRegex = r"(?P<comment>/\*\*(?:[^/]|/(?!\*\*))*\*/)"
functionRegex = r"(?P<function>\s\w+\s+(?P<functionName>\w+)\s*\()"

match = re.search(doxygenRegex + functionRegex, test)
print match.groupdict()
```

As long as this matches something, you can loop the regex matching - but starting the search at `test[match.end():]` next time. Hope that makes sense to you...

BTW if you only want to extract the comment and nothing about the function, you can use lookahead - just replace `functionRegex` with `r"(?=\s\w+\s+\w+\s*\()"`.

Comment: ...the trick being to make sure the "comment" regex can't match more than one comment at a time.  (You forgot to mention that, 'Dog.)  BTW, shouldn't the "function" regex start with `\s+` or `\s*`?

Comment: Yes, it will only match the very last comment before a function. And it could be `\s+`, right. As said, it's a simplified example.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achived using a single reg-ex.

The key is to capture the comment just before the desired function.
The easy way to do this is to use non-greedy qualifier.
For example: `/\*\*(.*?)\*/` with MULTILINE flag;
however, in Python, non-greedy and MULTILINE do not work together (at least on my environment).
So, you need a little trick like this:

`/\*\*((?:[^\*]|\*(?!/))*)\*/`.

This is to match:

1: the comment begin `/**`.

2: everything that is not `*` OR `*` that does not follows by `/`

3: the comment end `*/`.

From this idea the code you want is:

```
function_name  = "function2"
regex_comment  = "/\*\*((?:[^\*]|\*(?!/))*)\*/"
regex_static   = "(?:(\w+)\s*::\s*)?"
regex_function = "(\w+)\s+"+regex_static+"(?:"+function_name+")\s*\([^\)]*\)"
regex = re.compile(regex_comment+"\s*"+regex_function, re.MULTILINE)
text  = """
/**
    @doxygen comment1
*/
void test::function1()
{
}

/**
    @doxygen comment2
*/
void test::function2()
{
}
"""
match = regex.search(text)
if (match == None): print "None"
else:               print match.group(1)
```

When run, you got:

```
    @doxygen comment2
```

Variation:
If you want to capture `/**` and `*/` too, use `regex_comment  = "(/\*\*(?:[^\*]|\*(?!/))*\*/)"`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Note that C isn't a regular language, so it cannot be parsed by regular expressions. Have you considered leveraging doxygen itself to parse this file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do look-behind assertions with `(?<=...)` or `(?<!...)`, but in general you can only match forwards.

Comment: In .NET you could do a lookahead for the function followed by a lookbehind for the comment.  Unfortunately, in Python lookbehinds can only match fixed-length strings.

Answer (score 0):

The question is why are these comments not inside the function, so you can use **doc**.

But there is no easy way with regex.

Comment: he might be creating a python app to read doxygen comments in C or something

Answer (score 0):

here's a non regex approach, split on `*/` and find if the function you are looking for is at the next item. eg

```
test = """

/**
    @doxygen comment
*/
void function()
{
}

"""

t=test.split("*/")
for n,comm in enumerate(t):
    try:
        if "void" in t[n+1]:
             print t[n]
    except IndexError: pass
```